# Need help with this easy fact about functions

Tags: real-analysis

If $A$ is a set and $f: A \to \mathbb R$ is bounded and $M = \sup f(A), m = \inf f(A), M' = \sup |f(A)|, m' = \inf |f(A)|$ I want to show that

$$ M' - m' \le M-m$$

I seems easy enough but I got stuck and I just can't seem to finish the proof. What I did:

Given $\varepsilon > 0$ there are $x,y \in A$ with $M' \le |f(x)| + {\varepsilon \over 2} $ and $m' \ge |f(y)| + {\varepsilon \over 2}$. Then

$$ M' - m' \le |f(x)| - |f(y)| + \varepsilon \le |f(x) - f(y)| + \varepsilon$$

Now I need $|f(x) - f(y)| \le M-m$ but I just don't see why it should be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see $|f(x) - f(y)| \le M-m$, we can assume that $f(x)\geq f(y)$ without loss of generality (otherwise, we can interchange $x$ and $y$). Therefore, 
$$|f(x) - f(y)|=f(x)-f(y)\leq \big(\sup f(A)\big)-f(y)\leq  \big(\sup f(A)\big)-\big(\inf f(A)\big)=M-m$$
since $x, y\in A$.

Therefore, as you have proved, for any $\epsilon>0$, we have 
$$M'-m'\le M-m+\epsilon.$$
Since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, we have 
$$M'-m'\le M-m.$$